# Would collagen supplements affect C. diff?

Tags: gastroenterology, gut-microbiota-flora, collagen, flora, clostridium-difficile

I know that C. diff can [bind to collagen](https://journals.asm.org/doi/full/10.1128/IAI.70.10.5770-5778.2002) (or maybe just [broken down collagen](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/cmi.12139)?). Would a collagen supplement (specifically type 1 and 3) increase the germination in someone of C. diff in someone who’s colonized (i.e. increase rate of recurrence)?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the[reasons mentioned in [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: @CareyGregory Added some sources, are these sufficient?